# Is there a way to make a queue using array of structs using c++?

Tags: c++, queue

I was wondering how to make an array of structs into queue.
For example the structs are:

```cpp
struct Book
{
    string name;
    int bookID;
    string dateRent;
};

book list[5]; //declare array of structs
```

How can I make the struct as a queue? The queue supposedly has all three data.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::queue<Book> q;

Book b1 = {"Book One", 1, "01012020"}; 
Book b2 = {"Book Two", 2, "01012021"}; 

q.push(b1); 
q.push(b2); 

Book top_book = q.front(); 

cout << "top_boook_in_the_queue: " << top_book.name << " " << top_book.bookID << " " << top_book.dateRent << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if im understanding this right.
You wish to create array of structure Book.

```cpp
struct Book
{
    string name;
    int bookID;
    string dateRent;
};

Book arr[10];
```

This would be array of 10 elements for given structure Book in c++.

You can also create dynamic array like this

```cpp
Book* arr;
arr = new Book[10];
```

You can access elements like this

```cpp
arr[0].name;
arr[0].bookID;
arr[0].rentDate;
```

If you wish to create c++ structure that acts like a FIFO queue, you will have to create something like this

```cpp
struct Book
{
    string name;
    int bookID;
    string dateRent;
};

struct BookQueue {
    Book arr[10];
    int size = 0;
    void insert(Book book) {
        if (size == 10) return;
        for (int i = size-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
        }
        arr[0] = book;
        size++;
    }
    Book remove() {
        if (size < 0) return arr[0]; //it should throw error here
        size--;
        return arr[size];
    }
};
```

NOTE: This is bad for queue, but it is a structure queue, the simple one. For starters.